# Why can't I prune this directory?

Tags: find, busybox

`busybox version 1.33.0`

I'm trying to copy the entire `home` folder.

Inside of `home`, `/dev/sda2/` is mounted, like so:

```
/home/user/sda2
/home/user/sda2/root
/home/user/sda2/home_backup
```

Above you can see the `root/` directory within `sda2/`, owned by actual `root`. Also, there is `home_backup/` which will store files from `/home`.

**My issue is:**

After executing the following line I get a nice list of files, and `/home/user/sda2` and its contents are nowhere to be found, which is what I wanted:

```
LC_ALL=C find /home -path /home/user/sda2 -prune -o -iname '*' -print \;
```

But with the following, I always get the `operation not permitted` error for directory `root/` (is accurate, I'm not the owner, a regular user), meaning that it doesn't prune `sda2` as I expected:

```
LC_ALL=C find /home -path /home/user/sda2 -prune -o -iname '*' -exec cp -r '{}' /home/user/sda2/home_backup/ ;/
```

For obvious reasons `/home/user/sda2` must be excluded, to not copy the same data over and over.

Checking this doesn't really answer my question but it gave me a notion on how `prune` works.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489277/how-to-use-prune-option-of-find-in-sh/1489405#1489405

**EDIT**

I just realized that with the previous line all files will be all mixed up under `home_backup` but that's not an issue, I still want to know why I can't "prune" properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues with your commands. However the most significant is that you're doing a `cp -r`.
The command `find /home ... -iname '*'` is going to match every file and directory, including `/home` itself. So it's going to run `cp -r /home /home/user/sda2/home_backup/`, which is then going to include that mount.

There is no sane way to do this with `find`. Basically you're using the wrong tool for the job. Use `rsync`. Pass the `-x` option to tell it to not recursively copy the mount.

```
rsync -aHAXx /home /home/user/sda2/home_backup
```

---

If for some reason, you can't use `rsync` and/or you really want to use `find`, then you have to do this in multiple steps.

Your first step you need to create the directory structure:

```
find /home -mount -type d -execdir mkdir -p /home/user/sda2/home_backup/{} \;
```

Note the use of `-mount` instead of `-prune`. You could use `-prune`, but `-mount` is simpler. Also note the use of `-execdir`. This is so that `{}` is replaced with a relative path, and not an absolute path. If you want `/home/user/sda2/home_backup/home/...`, then you can use `-exec`.

Then you need to copy the files

```
find /home -mount \! -type d -execdir cp -a {} /home/user/sda2/home_backup/{} \;
```

Note here that to match files, we're instead matching everything other than directories. This is so that non-files, like symlinks and pipes are copied.

You could merge these into a single `find` command, but that just makes it messier.

All these little nuances are why `rsync` is a much better option.

Comment: Thank you, so far rsync is not available on the sytem. I might try to add it later on. At this moment what I'm trying is to limit the maxdepth option. Basically I want to keep the files structure.

Comment: You can't. Not sanely anyway. If you want insane then you need to do it in 2 steps. First `find` all directories, and then run `mkdir` inside your backup path to create them. Then `find` all files, and copy them (without `-r`). Your prune is fine. Though `-mount` or `-xdev` would be a better option.